# Phonegap Ajax CORS Request Proxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, proxy, cross-domain

I've seen a thousand threads addressing CORS, and none of them helped. I have a phonegap application that cannot make ajax requests because it seems it's going through a proxy. The ajax is quite simple.

```
$.ajax({
    url        : base_url + "submit_git",
    type       : "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    data       : {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName : lastName,
        email    : email,
        phone    : phone,
        comments : comments
    },
    dataType   : "json"
});
```

When I `console.log` the url, it gives me the correct url. When I follow the url, it returns the correct json, no 500 error. When I look at the console, I see the URL I'm requesting *prepended* with `http://192.168.1.109:3000/proxy/`. Following this I am returned with a blank page and a 500 error in the console. So it would seem that somehow phonegap thinks I want to go through this proxy. When I look in the phonegap logs I see

```
Proxy error for url: http://correcturl.com/page?query undefined
500 http://correcturl.com/page?query
```

I've added the cordova whitelist plugin and added `<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />` and this did nothing.

I've added

```
$.support.cors                 = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
```

And this did nothing.

I added `ProxyRequests Off` to the .htaccess, and this did nothing.

I added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src *" />` to my head, and this did nothing.

I **am** able to do a jsonp request to the same server without any issues. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**: 
I'm finding that this only happens when using the `phonegap serve` command and following the given IP. I was able to remove all phonegap files, upload just my html, css, and js and the request works fine.

**UPDATE 2**:
Well, I decided to develop and debug on a regular web server & localhost, then submit my changes to [build.phonegap.com](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) by zipping the contents of my www folder created w/ phonegap. Not technically a solution to the original issue, but it allows me to develop, debug then test on my phone.

Comment: same here - I can add that it started after SSL certificate update - app was intouched for 3 years...